# I'd like to animate the height

Tags: jquery, css

What Am I doing wrong?

```
$(".thumbnail").on('click', function(){
        $(this).animate({height:500},1500);
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PUdSn/

Comment: This is right, but the trailing `});` in your fiddle is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `});` in your sample. Fixed it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/PUdSn/5/

The code should be:

```
$(".thumbnail").on('click', function(){
   $(this).animate({height:"500px"},1500); //adding the px makes it clearer
});​
```

Comment: @metrampaz it does indeed, especially when it late at night :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing just a typo: you have extra `});` in your demo

```
            $(".thumbnail").on('click', function(){
                    $(this).animate({height:500},1500);     
            });

 }); // remove those!
```

## *[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PUdSn/4/)*

Answer (score 1):

There was a missing closing bracket and you missed `$(document).ready (function () { ... }`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".thumbnail").on('click', function() {
        $(this).animate({
            height: 500
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/PUdSn/2/)**

Comment: @KirkWoll Did you click and it didn't animate? It works for me here.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you only have a typo in that you have an extra `});`. This doesnt really change anything, but you could get rid of the on and just set up the click() method directly.

```
$(".thumbnail").click( function(){
   $(this).animate({height:"500px"},1500);
});​
```

Also, for future reference, this is easily caught using some sort of web developer toolkit. In IE it is built in and you only have to hit F12. In Chrome it is built in and you only have to hit Ctrl+Shift+I. And, in firefox, I do not believe it is built in, but you can use firebug and/or web dev as extensions. Hopefully that can help for future debugging purposes :)